# Why differs German and Swiss Number to String Conversion?

Tags: powershell, formatting

I'm just trying to convert a float I read from Exel to a string with using a comma as decimal separator and two digits behind the comma.
I try the following code

```
$a = 707.63790474
$l = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-CH")
"CH: " + $a.ToString("F2", $l)


$l = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
"DE: " + $a.ToString("F2", $l)

$l = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
"US: " + $a.ToString("F2", $l)
```

and get

```
CH: 707.64
DE: 707,64
US: 707.64
```

But to my knowledge a comma is used as decimal separator in Switzerland, unless it is a currency cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark. Do I miss something?

Comment: I wouldn't - I'd use decimals and let the language settings handle presentation/formatting.

Comment: No, you didn't miss something. That is absolutely right. I guess you'll have to use de-DE for the de-CH version aswell :( - Interesting find tough.

Comment: @OMG Ponies $a = 7.63; $a; "$a" yields 7,63
7.63 in Germany

Comment: NOPE - Switzerland definitely uses the **dot** (`.`) as the decimal point

Comment: @marc_s not all http://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04915/05016/index.html?lang=de

Comment: @bernd_k: any *normal* Swiss (non-Federal-employee) will use the dot - trust me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `(New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-CH")).numberFormat` to get numberformatinfo for de-CH

You'll get:

```
CurrencyDecimalDigits    : 2
CurrencyDecimalSeparator : .
IsReadOnly               : False
CurrencyGroupSizes       : {3}
NumberGroupSizes         : {3}
PercentGroupSizes        : {3}
CurrencyGroupSeparator   : '
CurrencySymbol           : Fr.
NaNSymbol                : n. def.
CurrencyNegativePattern  : 2
NumberNegativePattern    : 1
PercentPositivePattern   : 1
PercentNegativePattern   : 1
NegativeInfinitySymbol   : -unendlich
NegativeSign             : -
NumberDecimalDigits      : 2
NumberDecimalSeparator   : .
NumberGroupSeparator     : '
CurrencyPositivePattern  : 2
PositiveInfinitySymbol   : +unendlich
PositiveSign             : +
PercentDecimalDigits     : 2
PercentDecimalSeparator  : .
PercentGroupSeparator    : '
PercentSymbol            : %
PerMilleSymbol           : ‰
NativeDigits             : {0, 1, 2, 3...}
DigitSubstitution        : None
```

As you can see both NumberDecimalSeparator and CurrencyDecimalSeparator are .

Comment: `bernd_k`'s point is that, according to the Wikipedia article, .NET's handling of `de-CH` is incorrect. The `NumberDecimalSeparator` should be `,`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it looks like Switzerland uses `.` as the decimal separator (like normal people do), so this is correct output:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/forms/v3r5m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.form.designer.locales.doc%2Fi_xfdl_r_formats_de_CH.html

Comment: So with "normal people" you could mean either "the English-speaking peole", the "Swiss people", the "non-German people" or just "the majority of people". I wouldn't call any of these groups "normal" and not only because by your definition I'm not normal. Though I will neither elaborate on the US-English dominance (only the language, of course) over the world now, escpecially the computing world.

Comment: It's just insane that half the world uses a comma and the other half uses a period for this. Apparently the Swiss use apostrophes as separators as well, so what should be `100,000,000.00` is instead rendered as `100'000'000,00`. Im an American, but I'd be happy to switch from period to comma in the interest of universality.

Comment: @Christian: just to be annoying, "majority of people" = "normal" by definition.

Comment: @MusiGenesis This difference is indeed insane, but tell this the guys that came up with this some hundred years ago and didn't even know (not to talk about care) about other cultures. Cultural differences will always get in the way of globalization and standardization, but calling one side "normal" and the other one "un-normal" will bring you onto thin ice. Though I know you didn't mean it too serious and spared you of a down-vote.

Comment: Perhaps it is sane to use a point, when using a keyboard and to use the comma in handwriting. That is what some sane Swiss people told me. The funniest part is that this inconsistency is not  concerning them much.

Comment: @bernd_k: I think the Swiss have more important things to be concerned about, like the fact that their own government likes to plant explosives underneath busy roads.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: how come *you* know that (top-secret) fact ?!?! :-)

Comment: @marc_s: that's nothing - I also know if the light goes off when you close the refrigerator door.